# Access glyph contours through luaotfload

Tags: opentype, luaotfload

Can I access the countours that make up a glyph through `luaotfload`?

I can see that `luaotfload` contains (in `fontloader-font-ttf.lua`) code for parsing the `glyf` table, which should store the outlines under `fontdata.glyphs` – yet this subtable seems absent from the font itself, as it is not present in the output of the following:

```
\input luaotfload.sty
\font \test = {Latin Modern Roman} at 10pt \test
\directlua {
  local id = font.id('test')
  local testfont = font.getfont(id)
  for k,_ in pairs(testfont) do
    texio.write_nl(k)
  end
} \bye
```

So where *are* the glyph outlines stored? Is the glyf table parser I found above used at all? Is there some way I can call it myself?

Comment: Lualatex caches font information as a text lua table (e.g., `...\texlive\2020\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl\notoserifmyanmar-regular.lua`), from the looks of which (it's all metadata) the glyph shape/outline information is in the actual font file itself.

Comment: Outlines should be accessible via the low-level pdfliterals (e.g., `\pdfliteral{q 1 j 1 J 1 Tr}` from the `contour` package when in outline mode) - the literals give access to stroke, fill, colour, state, baseline shift, clipping, and so on.

Comment: The LuaTeX Reference Manual (do `texdoc luatex`) chapter 12 "The fontloader" has useful information, but for accessing and manipulating bezier curves etc directly (via lua??), (an API into) FontForge might be more apt, since the luatex fontloader "library is an adapted subset of FontForge and as such gives a similar view on a font (which has advantages when you want to debug)." (p 233)